# Google Websmasters - How to provide last updated date

Tags: google, google-search-console, search-engine-indexing

One of my e-commerce sites with daily product uploads has sitemap listed has below. Recently we notice that google index rate  has slowed down.

```
<url>
<loc>
http://urllink
</loc>
<lastmod>2016-07-22</lastmod>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
```

Could it be because our automatically generated site map structured, wherein lastmod date is being shown as the previous date every day i.e. it tells google that this product has been changed the previous day when in fact it hasn't been. Does that mean Google will expend resources, try to see what has changed and if it hasn't changed it probably will starting assigning lower priority to our site and hence we run the risk of our more recently added products not being indexed.

We also have a feeling that this lastmod date error is probably eating a lot of our server resources too.

Hope that was clear. Thanks

Comment: I've never liked the idea of updating `<lastmod>` every day. It's not just wrong, it's misleading search engines.

Comment: @AndrewLott Agree with you - unfortunately, we are using a auto sitemap creator and that is causing this problem. We will have to look for a way to solve this. - And thanks for the link of the possible duplicate - yes that is indeed the answer i was looking for. However, I am also looking for a way to turn this off in my sitemap creator.

Comment: I've just written an answer there too. Having it update every day probably isn't the biggest problem to worry about, but you might have the option of just leaving the `<lastmod>` off entirely; that'll make the file itself smaller and quicker for search engines to read as well.

Comment: @AndrewLott Thanks for that. One small query, if lastmod is left off entirely, doesnt google have to compare all possible links and figure out which is the new content. Alternatively, if we do provide lastmod, doesn't it help google (and us) is saving valuable computing resources.

Comment: If you have _useful_ lastmod values, it could be helpful to search engines. But if you tell them you've updated every day, when you don't, it's probably more likely to be ignored.

Comment: Lastmod is largely ignored anyway. Google takes *nothing* directly from sitemaps into the index. The URL index exists as a result primarily of crawling following links. Where a sitemap is best is for pages where there are no links. The sitemap is primarily used to audit the site to ensure that it can be crawled. If URLs are presented in the sitemap that do not exist in the URL index and there are no dangling links for the URL in the link index, that URL is submitted to the fetch queue. From there, if the page can be fetched, it is added to the URL index. This is far from immediate.